# ASP.NET MVC Displaying multiple partial views inside a folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Application broken down into multiple areas.
The structure is like this:
Areas > AreaName > Views > various view folders

I need to add a folder inside these view folders called HelpFiles making the structure like this
Areas > AreaName > Views > various view folders > HelpFiles

In my Layout page, I have an icon when its clicked, it will call a controller method that will return all partial views inside the HelpFiles folder and display them inside a div.

What I have done so far:
I have added a method to the basecontroller like this:

```
   public ActionResult ShowHelpText(string viewName)
        {
            var areaName = ControllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
            var folderName = "~"+ areaName + viewName + "HelpFiles/";
            ViewBag.Partials = ????
            return View();
        }
```

On the returning view my code is like this:

```
@foreach (string partial in ViewBag.Partials)
{
    //Html.RenderPartial(partial);
    @Html.Partial(partial)
}
```

My problem is I am not able to figure a way to get all the views from a folder.

I realize this is not the ideal way of doing this, the help text should come from a database etc, however due to a CMS service tie in, we are stuck with this structure for now.

Any help or pointers will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is not the best location to put your help files. Put them in the Content folder. if not exist, then create a folder named Content et put your HelpFiles sub-folder.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is not the ideal way to do this, however this is not a choice thats left on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code, you might need to make some little changes in order to make it work.

```
//Replace the `~/Content/HelpFiles` to the real path.
ViewBag.Partials = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/HelpFiles")).Select(i => Path.GetFileName(i));
```

View:

```
@foreach (string partial in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Partials)
{
    @Html.Partial(partial)
}
```

Comment: That is the way to go. Thank you. My finished code was like this:
  ViewBag.Partials = Directory.EnumerateFiles(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(folderName)).Select(i => Path.GetFileName(i));
            ViewBag.Path = folderName;
            return View("~/areas/common/views/base/showhelptext.cshtml");

@foreach (string partial in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Partials)
{
    string path = ViewBag.Path + partial;
    @Html.Partial(path)
}